# Activate cell's accessory view (UISwitch) when didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiswitch, didselectrowatindexpath

Every cell of my tableView has a UISwitch as an accessoryView:

```
UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
cell.accessoryView = mySwitch;
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(SwitchToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Switch is toggled when the user taps it, but I also want it toggled when the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called (when the user taps on that cell).

I tried this (but it doesn't work):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    UISwitch *tempSwitch = (UISwitch *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView;
    [tempSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(SwitchToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; // cell selection fadeout animation
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when it "does not work"? No action at all, as if the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` were not there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code must look like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    UISwitch *tempSwitch = (UISwitch *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView;
    [tempSwitch setOn:!tempSwitch.on animated:YES];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Remember that you also have to update your model.

Comment: That toggles the switch but doesn't call the (switchToggle:) action that updates my model. I'll make a workaround to fix that. Thanks!

Comment: The "workaround" would be to add this line: `[self switchToggle:tempSwitch];`.